# How to track pop-up modal on Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

```
const products = await page.$$('.product-list li .hover-overlay');

for (var a = 2; a <= products.length; a++) {
  await Promise.all([
    page.hover(`.product-list li:nth-child(${a}) .hover-overlay`),
    page.click(`.product-list li:nth-child(${a}) .hover-overlay`),
    page.waitForSelector('.modal', { visible: true }),
    page.waitForSelector('.save-btn', { visible: true }),
    page.click('.save-btn'),
  ])
}
```

this is the error

```
Error: No node found for selector: .save-btn
```

puppeteer : ^1.7.0

node : v9.4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Promise.all` will let all the promises run to fulfillment simultaneously, so here you’re simultaneously hovering and clicking on a particular element, waiting for two selectors, and clicking on an element matching the last one. You can perform these actions in a sequence by using `await` inside the loop as well:

```
const products = await page.$$('.product-list li .hover-overlay');

for (const overlay of products.slice(2)) {
  await overlay.hover();
  await overlay.click();
  await page.waitForSelector('.modal', { visible: true });
  const button = await page.waitForSelector('.save-btn', { visible: true });
  await button.click();
  await page.waitForFunction('.modal', { hidden: true });
}
```

I’m using references to the elements themselves to avoid repeatedly searching for them. I’m assuming you call `hover` on the overlay before clicking because the page won’t register a click without hovering first; if that’s not the case, you can leave out the `hover` entirely.

Comment: Thank you, I can see now the modal selector. But the modal is not looping again? I want to hover and click this `products` around 10-20 elements. 
What I want to achieve is
hover -> click -> modal -> save ---> repeat ;  base on `products.length`

Comment: I found out now, why it is not looping. Because the modal is not waiting to close. Before it hover and click again.

Comment: That’s a bit tricky to get around. We’d need to see what changes in the HTML between when the button is clicked and when the modal is completely gone. Then we could probably use either `waitForSelector` or `waitForFunction` to check for that condition after the `click()`.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm trying to do. But the modal selector is not showing in the html DOM after the `.save-btn` was clicked . And no trace for modal selector that the modal was gone. Is there a way to check on puppeteer that the waitFor(ElementToHide) ? anyways thank you

Comment: I’ve updated the answer to wait for `.modal` to disappear from the DOM. I hope I’ve understood correctly.